# Improve load speed of side nav links on blog, or include loading indicator

Tags: feature-request, blog, performance

When visiting [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) I noticed that it takes a long time for pages to load when clicking on the links in the left navigation sidebar. In addition, there is no visual indicator that anything is happening since these pages are loaded asynchronously. For me the pages take an average of about 3 seconds to load.  When I first clicked on the links I thought they were broken since nothing happened. In my opinion if it takes more than a second there should be a visual loading animation or other indicator. I am not sure if I am the only one who is experiencing this since no one else acknowledged it.

Here is a screen recording showing my experience:

[image: screen recording of a user clicking links in the blog left navigation]

Interestingly if I visit one of the pages directly (i.e. https://stackoverflow.blog/career-advice/), it loads pretty fast.

Comment: I take it from the downvotes that it's working fine for others? Or that it's just not that big of a deal?

Comment: For me, there is a quite noticeable delay after clicking where I start to wonder if the page really registered the click. Ironically, it's both faster and provides more user feedback with the single-page application JavaScript disabled and reloading the entire page each time. In other words, in its current form having it as a single page application is a worse experience than if just navigating to the pages.

Comment: I suspect, I don’t know, it’s a marketing web site, the goal isn’t performance.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 Every website should be able to perform to a minimum standard, especially with the internet speeds we have now. Besides that, my concern was mostly about usability. The link appears to be broken and that will turn away some people. If you think about it as nothing but a marketing site, then just remove the ajax functionality since it doesn't need it. It actually loads faster using regular page loads as Mayken mentioned.

Comment: Sure. I’m just saying that’s not always going to be the primary goal, or even on the radar. With the way this was introduced I very much suspect it was “release on <date> at all costs {for whatever reasons a business might think that’s the most important thing}, we’ll tidy up later.”

Comment: Also, I do have to wonder if this change has happened in part because blog management has been outsourced. Maybe it was before, too, and now it's just a different 3rd party. In either of those scenarios, it's not like a Stack dev can just go make improvements, futz with JavaScript, and so on. Stack would just be submitting bugs or asking for feature requests, like we do of them. :-)

Comment: @Stuckat1337 Perhaps you are right, I did notice the ajax requests for the page content were going to `api.sanity.io`. In that case they could file a ticket with the third party. But it looked like it is using the [Stacks design components](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks/) so I thought they might be able to inject some javascript to at least have a spinner.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 SE devs can make changes, they already fixed several bugs in the blogs. I'm pretty sure they can't, and won't, improve the speed, but can add loading indicator of some sort.

Comment: Worth to mention, the SE dev handling the blog did mention improving the initial loading speed by "tweaking the cache" or something like that.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 The issue isn't, really, that the page loads are slow. The slowness is a problem, but it's not the primary issue. The problem is that the user clicks something and gets *no indication* that the click was received by the page and that the action is being acted upon. This breaks user engagement with the page and, often, causes the user to think something is significantly wrong, potentially resulting in them re-clicking and/or navigating away. It's relatively trivial to provide an activity indicator. SE even has a couple different stock activity indicators which could be used.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Yes, I did notice that the initial page load speed was also slow, but after the SE dev made that fix, the initial page load speed was improved.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed for the most part. However, as Shadow mentioned there are still a few places where there is some slowness. For instance viewing a [tag page](https://stackoverflow.blog/silos). Also, the "show more" button on that page doesn't do anything.

Comment: Still slow in some places e.g. viewing a [tag page](https://stackoverflow.blog/silos), and "show more" broken.